# How long does it take, and how much heat, to raise the temperature of air in a box?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, radiation, cooling

I am seeking to crudely model a house with a window as a perfectly insulated box with a hole (which only allows radiative heat).

My question is to find how the temperature of air in the box changes over time. Would it be at all valid to apply Newton's law of cooling, with surface area equal to the area of the hole in the box?

Then, I would like to complicate the problem a little more and add a heater to the box. So that heat is pumped in (or out). In this situation, what becomes the time dependency of the temperature?

I have taken a few cracks at this, but I am quite sure I haven't done it properly.

Finally, once the time dependency is understood, I would like to find the heat required to raise the box to a certain temperature as a function of the hole area.

If necessary as a follow up, I can offer some of my efforts at a solution -- but because I'm quite sure they are wrong, I'm curious if anyone can offer their input.

Thank you!

Addendum: Assuming the air in the box can be treated as an object, and that the heat transfer rate may be approximated by Law of Cooling, then:

dQhole/dt = A*U*Delta(T(t)); where A is the hole area, U is some resistance to heat transfer (if the hole were a window, for example), Delta(T(t)) is the temperature inside(t) - Temperature outside, and t is time.

So, it seems Qhole = Integral(A*U*Delta(T)dt). Or, in other words, Qhole is the energy lost through the hole after time t.

If the 'heater' is added (dQheater/dt = constant), the total energy in the system:

Qinside = (Qheater)*t - Qhole = (Qheater)*t - Integral(A*U*Delta(T(t))dt)

and from law of cooling T(t) = Toutside + (T(0)-Toutside)e^((-AU/mc)t)
where m is the mass of the air, and c is the specific heat capacity.

So, plugging that into the Qinside equation gets that long old thing...

How am I doing, ha!

Comment: Yes, please show your efforts to find a solution. It seems that a balance of the incoming, outgoing, and resident energy terms would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be at all valid to apply Newton's law of cooling, with
> surface area equal to the area of the hole in the box?

No. You yourself specified that the box is perfectly insulated, meaning no convective or conductive losses take place. Newton's Law of cooling concerns only convective losses.

But it would be possible to model using something analogous, using [Stefan Boltzmann Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stefan%E2%80%93Boltzmann_law):

$$P=A\epsilon \tau \left(T^4-T_{\infty}^4\right)$$

where $T_{\infty}$ is the environment temperature.

With $P$ the only loss, Newton's law could then be rewritten as the ODE:

$$C\frac{\text{d}T(t)}{\text{d}t}=-A\epsilon \tau \left[T(t)^4-T_{\infty}^4\right]\tag{1}$$

where $C$ is the *total heat capacity of the box* (walls and air included). Of course here it is assumed that the box' temperature us always homogeneous.

ODE $(1)$ is separable and thus easy to integrate (but define initial condition firstly).

---

The model can be expanded with a heater of power $W$ using a simple heat balance, during the transient:

$$\text{heat in}=\text{heat out}+\text{heat retained}$$
$$W=A\epsilon \tau \left[T(t)^4-T_{\infty}^4\right]+C\frac{\text{d}T(t)}{\text{d}t}\tag{2}$$

> I would like to find the heat required to raise the box to a certain
> temperature as a function of the hole area.

ODE $(2)$, which can also be easily integrated, will answer that question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will play with this.

Comment: Do you mean *conductive* losses (through the walls)? I agree there will also be no *convective* losses because the air is trapped in the house, but contextually it seems like you meant the former.

Comment: The OP used the term *perfectly insulated box*. I've edited my answer slightly. Ta.